# Racket R5RS "no #%app syntax transformer is bound"

Tags: namespaces, eval, racket, r5rs

I'm trying to execute the following R5RS code in Racket:

```
#lang r5rs
(define boo 100)
(define lib `(begin 88 99 99 ,boo))
(eval lib (interaction-environment))
```

However this results in the error:

```
begin: unbound identifier;
also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound
at: begin
in: (begin 88 99 99 100)
```

In normal racket I can solve this using namespace anchors, as follows:

```
#lang racket
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))
(define boo 100)
(define lib `(begin 88 99 99 ,boo))
(eval lib ns)
```

But as R5RS does not feature  *define-namespace-anchor* I cannot solve it this way.
How do I modify the R5RS environment so that the original code works ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to file this as a bug -- but a solution to the bug would be to make the function throw an error because this function is supposed to give you the environment that the user interacts with, and there is no interaction here.

(And I don't know what you're trying to do, but I think that you should use `(scheme-report-environment 5)` to make up an environment.)

Comment: Well I'm trying to run the SRFI 72 reference implementation (http://www.het.brown.edu/people/andre/macros/index.htm) in racket, but the program breaks on its use of *(eval variable (interaction-environment))* which should work in a standard r5rs implementation?

Comment: (1) If you're trying to run that, then it'll be better to start with the Racket-specific code (which is there under the previous name of "mzscheme"); (2) I don't know this implementation, but I note that in the comments there is a note that says: "All runtime uses of eval [...] have been removed."; (3) this is a library that implements a low-level macro system (`syntax-case`) -- and I doubt that this is possible in R5RS, at least not in the way that this library implements it.